# Is my Godaddy IIS7 SSL certificate reliable?

Tags: ssl-certificate

I have purchased & installed Godaddy SSL certificate. When I access the site using Chrome 24ver the https padlock shows
1) encrypted with 128-bit
2) uses TLS 1.0
3) encrypted using RC4_128 with SHA1

However I read that RC4 is not safe anymore. So my question is
1) How reliable is https connection with mentioned specs
2) How do I get AES_CBC certificate?
3) I was being told that since the server is windows hosted it cannot be upgraded to 256-bit. Is it true? If not then what should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing things up. There is no RC4 certificate or AES_CBC certificate.

You certificate is signed by a certificate authority that issued it. In your case it is Godaddy. Look for **Signature Algorithm** property when you open details of the certificate (i.e. doubleclick on certificate file). There will probably be something like sha1RSA or sha256RSA or something similar.

RC4 is a cipher that is negotiated when establishing SSL conection with server. It depends on both parties (client and server) witch algorithm they will use. Read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer#TLS_handshake). You can set up IIS to allow or disallow these [ciphers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245030/en-us).

Comment: Oh sorry thank you for clearly my confusion.....but does the selection of algorithm also dependent upon the OS on which the browser runs?

Comment: my confusion arised after I read the following at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer#Cipher there its mentioned that RC4 is insecure.....

Comment: Client and server must agree on one cipher that both parties understand. So it depends on the browser and its implementation. If the browser uses some OS library for cryptography than it depends on that library which cipher suites it implements.